# Student's t-distribution cumulative distribution function

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

**Background**:

In the context of the Student's t-distribution cumulative distribution function, denoted as $F_\nu(t)$ where $\nu$ represents the degrees of freedom, R Version 4.3.1's `?dt` documentation highlights the following result for $t \in (-\infty,\infty)$ :

$\begin{split}
 F_\nu(t) & = 1- I_{\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2}}\biggr(\frac{\nu}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\biggr) \\
 & = 1- \frac{\beta\biggr(\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2}, \frac{\nu}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\biggr)}{\beta\biggr(\frac{\nu}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\biggr)} \\
 & = 1- \frac{\int_0^{\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2}} x^{\frac{\nu}{2}-1} (1-x)^{\frac{1}{2}-1} dx}{\int_0^1 x^{\frac{\nu}{2}-1} (1-x)^{\frac{1}{2}-1} dx} 
 \end{split}$

**Approach**:

To prove this result, consider the integral representation of $F_\nu (t)$ for $t<0$ as follows:

$$\begin{split}
  F_\nu (t) & = \int_{-\infty}^t \frac{1}{\sqrt{\nu}\beta(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\nu}{2})}(1 + \frac{s^2}{\nu})^{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}} ds \\
  & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\nu}\beta(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\nu}{2})} \int_{-\infty}^t (1 + \frac{s^2}{\nu})^{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}} ds \\
  & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\nu}\beta(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\nu}{2})} \int_{-\infty}^t (\frac{\nu + s^2}{\nu})^{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}} ds
  \end{split}$$

- **Variable Transformation**:

Apply the following variable change based on what is pointed out in Kaplan, Wilfred. Advanced Calculus. 5th ed, Addison-Wesley, 2003. page 236

$\begin{split}
 x & = \frac{\nu}{\nu + s^2} \text{ where } s < 0 \\
 s^2 & = \frac{\nu(1-x)}{x} \\
 \sqrt{s^2} & = \sqrt{\frac{\nu(1-x)}{x}} \\
 |s| & = \sqrt{\frac{\nu(1-x)}{x}} \\
 -s & = \sqrt{\frac{\nu(1-x)}{x}} \\
  s & = - \sqrt{\frac{\nu(1-x)}{x}} \\
  ds & = -\frac{1}{2} \biggr[ \frac{\nu(1-x)}{x} \biggr]^{-\frac{1}{2}} \biggr[ -\frac{\nu}{x^2}\biggr]dx
 \end{split}$

- **Integration Process**

$$\begin{split}
  F_\nu (t) & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\nu}\beta(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\nu}{2})} \int_{0}^{\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2}} \biggr[ \frac{1}{x} \biggr]^{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}} \frac{\nu}{2x^2\sqrt{\nu(\frac{1-x}{x})}}dx \text{ where } x = \frac{\nu}{\nu + s^2} \text{ and } s < 0 \\
  & = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\beta(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\nu}{2})} \int_{0}^{\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2}} x^{\frac{\nu}{2}-1}(1-x)^{-\frac{1}{2}} dx \\
  & = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\beta(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\nu}{2})} \int_{0}^{\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2}} x^{\frac{\nu}{2}-1}(1-x)^{\frac{1}{2}-1} dx \\
  & = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\beta(\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2};\frac{\nu}{2},\frac{1}{2})}{\beta(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\nu}{2})} \\ 
  & = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\beta(\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2};\frac{\nu}{2},\frac{1}{2})}{\beta(\frac{\nu}{2},\frac{1}{2})} \text{Because } \beta(a,b) = \beta(b,a) \\ 
  & = \frac{1}{2} I_{\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2}}\biggr(\frac{\nu}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\biggr) \\
  \end{split}$$

**Challenges**:

- **Inconsistency with the theorical result pointed out in R Version 4.3.1's `?dt` documentation**: $\frac{1}{2} I_{\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2}}\biggr(\frac{\nu}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\biggr)$ is not the same as $1- I_{\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2}}\biggr(\frac{\nu}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\biggr)$. I want to know if my proof is incorrect.
- **Case Analysis**: The provided derivation is valid only for $t<0$. I need to find a proof that also cover the cases where $t=0$ and $t>0$.
- **Discrepancy with R Version 4.3.1**: There exists a notable inconsistency between the theoretical computation and the output obtained from R version 4.3.1. I require clarification regarding why the theoretical result pointed out in R Version 4.3.1's `?dt` documentation fails to align with the actual outcome, as demonstrated in the following code snippet:

```
v <- 5
t <- -1

## Student's t-distribution cumulative distribution function
pt(q = t, df = v, lower.tail = TRUE, ncp = 0)
#> [1] 0.1816087

## Application of the theorical result using the proof I propose
0.5*pbeta(q = v / (v + t^2), shape1 = v/2, shape2 = 1/2, 
          ncp = 0,lower.tail = TRUE)
#> [1] 0.1816087

## Application of the theorical result where there is a discrepancy 
## based on what is mentioned in R Version 4.3.1's ?dt documentation
1 - pbeta(q = v / (v + t^2), shape1 = v/2, shape2 = 1/2, 
          ncp = 0,lower.tail = TRUE)
#> [1] 0.6367825
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: 0.1816087 = (1 - 0.6367825) / 2

Comment: The issues regarding **Inconsistency with the theoretical result mentioned in R Version 4.3.1's ?dt documentation** and **Discrepancy with R Version 4.3.1** have been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77259151/students-t-distribution-cdf-r-base-documentation)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the issues related to R Version 4.3.1's `?dt`, they had been addressed [here](https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18610) by Martin Mächler (R Project Core Developer)

For the case of $t \geq 0$ we can find $F_{\nu}(t)$ in the following way:

$$\begin{split}
  F_{\nu}(t) & = F_{\nu}(0) + F_{\nu}(t) -  F_{\nu}(0)\\
  & = \frac{1}{2} + \int_0^{t} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\nu}\beta(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\nu}{2})}(1 + \frac{s^2}{\nu})^{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}} ds \\
  & = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\nu}\beta(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\nu}{2})} \int_{1}^{\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2}} \biggr[\frac{1}{x}\biggr]^{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}} \frac{-\nu}{2x^2\sqrt{\nu(\frac{1-x}{x})}}dx \text{ where } x = \frac{\nu}{\nu + s^2} \text{ and } s \geq 0 \\
  & = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\nu}\beta(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\nu}{2})} \int_{\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2}}^{1} \biggr[\frac{1}{x}\biggr]^{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}} \frac{-\nu}{2x^2\sqrt{\nu(\frac{1-x}{x})}}dx \\
  & = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\beta(\frac{\nu}{2},\frac{1}{2})} \int_{\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2}}^{1} x^{\frac{\nu}{2}-1}(1-x)^{\frac{1}{2}-1} dx \\
  \end{split}$$

Also we have the following result:

$$\begin{split}
 \frac{\int_{0}^{\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2}} x^{\frac{\nu}{2}-1}(1-x)^{\frac{1}{2}-1} + \int_{\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2}}^{1} x^{\frac{\nu}{2}-1}(1-x)^{\frac{1}{2}-1}}{\beta(\frac{\nu}{2},\frac{1}{2})} & = 1 \\
 \frac{1}{\beta(\frac{\nu}{2},\frac{1}{2})} \int_{\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2}}^{1} x^{\frac{\nu}{2}-1}(1-x)^{\frac{1}{2}-1} & = 1  - I_{\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2}}\biggr(\frac{\nu}{2},\frac{1}{2}\biggr) \\
  \end{split}$$

Therefore we have that:

$$\begin{split}
  F_{\nu}(t) & = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\beta(\frac{\nu}{2},\frac{1}{2})} \int_{\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2}}^{1} x^{\frac{\nu}{2}-1}(1-x)^{\frac{1}{2}-1} dx \\
 & = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\biggr[ 1  - I_{\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2}}\biggr(\frac{\nu}{2},\frac{1}{2}\biggr) \biggr] \\
 & = 1 - \frac{1}{2}I_{\frac{\nu}{\nu + t^2}}\biggr(\frac{\nu}{2},\frac{1}{2}\biggr) \text{ where } t \geq 0
\end{split}$$

For more details about $F_{\nu}(t)$ check out Johnson, N. L., Kotz, S., & Balakrishnan, N. (1995). Continuous univariate distributions (2nd ed, Vol. 2). Wiley. Chapter 28, page 364, equations 28.3 & 28.4a